# UIWebView eating all memory for loadRequest in iPad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have read about lot of leak issues with UIWebView But my case is very simple so I decided to go for a new question. 
When I try to load a file from WebView loadRequest method the memory **allocation** keeps on increasing if I watch in Instruments. But if I see the leaks there is no leaks at all in instruments.

I am using 4.3 sdk so I guess it has to be latest issue.

I have gone through  this article
[Why UIWebView Eating so many Memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079452/why-uiwebview-eating-so-many-memory)
and this article http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/04/UIWebView-secrets-part1-memory-leaks-on-xmlhttprequest

but nothing seems to work for me.

```
@interface MyView: UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {

IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

=========
inside my MyView Class

```
@synthesize webView;

-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", pathString]];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]] ];

}

-(void)dealloc {

   [webView release];

}
```

Waiting for your replies.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good formatting is your friend

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging the following delegate method?

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
   NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}
```